# cypress coverage doesn't work with vue-property-decorator

Tags: typescript, code-coverage, cypress, instabug

I wanna have code coverage on frontend with cypress. Currently cypress recommends istanbul for coverage. Unfortunately I can't use it in pair of the stack below:

- vue-property-decorator
- cypress
- istanbul code coverage.
- typescript.

Because of:
 - I didn't find a way to make istanbul work with ts-loader, because istanbul-intementer-loader [uses babel under the hood](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/istanbul-instrumenter-loader/blob/master/package.json#L43)
 - babel-loader doesn't support decorators in the same way that typescript does, that [breaks vue-property-decorator](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator/issues/26). Using vue in typescript w/o vue-property-decorator is not that neat...

Here're some useful link:

- [example for repo with babel coverage](https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage)
- [official guide](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage.html#See-code-coverage-summary)
- [official github repo for typescript users](https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage#typescript-users)
- [cypress issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage/issues/97)

[Here's](https://github.com/akoidan/vue-webpack-typescript) the repo and quick overview:

- `git clone https://github.com/akoidan/vue-webpack-typescript && cd vue-webpack-typescript`
- `yarn install`
- `yarn run build`
- `yarn run e2e`

You can also check out the babel branch on the repo above, to see example with babel instead of ts-loader

Here's the example of setup with ts-loader:

**package.json**:

```
{
  "nyc": {
    "extends": "@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript",
    "all": true
  }
}
```

**cypress/iintegration/sample_spec.ts**:

```
describe('My first Test', function() {
    it('Does not much', function() {
        cy.visit('/');
        cy.contains('Filtered Users');
    })
});
```

**cypress/plugins/index.js**:

```
module.exports = (on) => {
    on('task', require('@cypress/code-coverage/task'));
    on('file:preprocessor', require('@cypress/code-coverage/use-browserify-istanbul'));
};
```

**cypress/support/index.js**:

```
import './commands'
import '@cypress/code-coverage/support';
```

**test chrome devtool**:

```
window.__coverage__ // undefined
```

**stdout**:

```
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- there's seem to be no way to make coverage work with ts-loader
- babel 7 +  babel-preset-typescript-vue are required to make it work with vue-property-decorator

Here's the example of github repo with working [codecov](https://github.com/akoidan/vue-webpack-typescript)